# libnativehelper missing variant in Android build

Tags: android, build, partition

I'm trying to compile a JNI in the Android product partition. For that purpose I added the property `product_specific: true` in the Android.bp such as:

```
cc_library_shared {
    name : "..."
    ...
       shared_libs: [
            "libandroidicu",
            "libnativehelper",
            "libcutils",
            "libutils",
            "liblog",
        ],
    proprietary : false;
    product_specific: true
```

Unfortunately, at compilation I have the following error :

> Android.bp:1:1: dependency "libnativehelper" of "libTest_jni" missing variant:
>   os:android, image:product.30, arch:arm64_armv8-a, sdk:, link:shared, version:1
>
> available variants:
>   os:android, image:, arch:arm64_armv8-a, sdk:, link:shared, version:
>   os:android, image:, arch:arm64_armv8-a, sdk:, link:shared, version:1
>   os:android, image:, arch:arm64_armv8-a, sdk:, link:static, version:
>   os:android, image:, arch:arm64_armv8-a, sdk:, link:static, version:1
>   os:android, image:, arch:arm_armv8-a, sdk:, link:shared, version:
>   os:android, image:, arch:arm_armv8-a, sdk:, link:shared, version:1
>   os:android, image:, arch:arm_armv8-a, sdk:, link:static, version:
>   os:android, image:, arch:arm_armv8-a, sdk:, link:static, version:1

How can I add a product variant to libnativehelper?

Comment: I have a similar problem, but with "sdk:sdk" property.

Comment: Did you get any workaround? I am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

libnativehelper is part of non-sdk inerfaces. So we can't use it in the product partition. If you  do the reverse engineering, system will give the exact library which using the non-sdk interfaces...

Comment: what do you need to do to reverse engineer? I am guessing you are saying find the exact libraries used by the non-sdk interface. In this case that's the libraries that libnativehelper uses.